# PLC PointCloud subscribing

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl, sensor, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm doing a project on motion detection and and gesture recognition and I have to extract and subscribe to the PointCloud2 sensor messages on the Kinect device using openni but I am new to ROS and have no idea how to do it. I've been reading: [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#Subscribing_to_point_clouds)

However, whenever I try to run the examples, I get the following:

`fatal error: pcl/point_cloud.h: No such file or directory` but I have installed the PCL library, so, might it have something to do with my CMake file not including something?

Could someone please link me or try to explain how I would possibly Subscribe to the PointCloud and have a callback function which publishes the data that is being extracted on my own topic?

Thanks

P.S.

I have tried to implement the following:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;

void callback(const PointCloud::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  printf ("Cloud: width = %d, height = %d\n", msg->width, msg->height);
  BOOST_FOREACH (const pcl::PointXYZ& pt, msg->points)
  printf ("\t(%f, %f, %f)\n", pt.x, pt.y, pt.z);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   ros::init(argc, argv, "sub_pcl");
   ros::NodeHandle nh;
   ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<PointCloud>("points2", 1, callback);
   ros::spin();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107746/plc-pointcloud-subscribing/) by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2013-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using the command:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

to bring up the kinect, then you should subscribe to one of the "points" topic using a sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 message.
So you have to include in your code:

```
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
```

Then if you want to use this point cloud with PCL you have to convert it using the pcl_conversions package. I suggest you yo look at [this](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL) link!

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on 2013-12-06**:
@Tirjen  Hey. If I did not want to use the PCL, can I just subscribe to the sensor_msgs/PointCloud.h and then extract the data from this?

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-12-08**:
Yes of course!! But the message is sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h!